# how do I set up mocking using mockito in netbeans in a java maven project?

Tags: maven, netbeans, mockito

how to I set up mocking using mockito in netbeans in a java maven project? I understand mocking but cant find mockito files in the maven repo

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're manually setting up your pom.xml in NetBeans, I think this is what you want:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using Mockito in a Java project right now, but fair warning, I'm using Ivy for dependency management, not Maven.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19

Comment: Actually, I have done this already discovered that removing static from the import made it work fine.  Thanks for your help!