# How to setup Mockito straight in NetBeans's simple Java project

Tags: java, netbeans, mockito

Googled for quite a while, speaking of Mockito's setup, everyone talks about Moven, Gradle, and some other building tools(like in this post [how do I set up mocking using mockito in netbeans in a java maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555735/how-do-i-set-up-mocking-using-mockito-in-netbeans-in-a-java-maven-project)), which I don't understand yet.

I have a simple Java Application project created in NetBeans for a while, if I use Moven, I would have to re-create a Maven project in NetBeans, and it will has a lot things I won't use.

Can I just set Mockito up in my current project simply? Without Maven, without Gradle....

Answer (score 1):

First you have to **download** the [**Mockito binaries**](http://mockito.org/). Put them somewhere useful (eg. into a `lib` dir within your project).

At your project in your Netbeans:

*Right Click* on **`Test Libraries`** -> **`Add JAR/Folder`** select the downloaded binaries.

In most cases it's a good idea to add source / doc too.

---

If you use Mockito for other projects too, it's a good idea to create a library for it (**`Tools`** -> **`Libraries`**).